# "Cannot read property 'selectedZones' of undefined" on a already initialized and not empty variable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a component that filters the build zones with the selected zones in ngOnInit

**rfid.component.ts**

```
@Component(...)
export class RfidComponent implements OnInit {

  gridApi: GridApi;
  partList = new BehaviorSubject<IPart>(null);
  selectedZones: string[] = [];

  constructor(private zvSelectionService: ZvSelectionService) {
  }

  isInBuildZone(bom: IBomLine): boolean {
    return this.selectedZones.includes(bom.buildZone);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedZones = this.zvSelectionService.selectedZones.map(zone => zone.name);
    console.log(this.selectedZones) // -> ["LM3"]

    of(partList).pipe(
      map((list: IPart) => ({...list, bomLines: list.bomLines.filter(this.isInBuildZone)})),
      filter((list: IPart) => list.bomLines.length > 0),
    )
      .subscribe(data => this.partList.next(data));
  }
}
```

But I get the following error, even though the selectedZones are initialized and not empty:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedZones' of undefined
    at isInBuildZone (rfid.component.ts:50)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    ...
```

Comment: If I would have to guess from the provided code, it should be at `zvSelectionService.selectedZones` . The error says that `you are reading "selectedZones" from undefined value`. Is there more code to it ? .

Comment: zvSelectionService.selectedZones returns just an array from the local storage, so it's not asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the function invoking to the component class

```
map((list: IPart) => ({...list, bomLines: list.bomLines.filter(this.isInBuildZone.bind(this))})),
```